# Can I add to or change the default CSS class when using ValidationMessage in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am using **ValidationMessage** in a razor component to show validation message, like this:

```
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => ViewModel.CompanyNumber)" />
```

This generates this HTML code:

```html
<div class="validation-message">The company number field is required.</div>
```

Is it possible to change the CSS-class? I want to use something else than `validation-message`. Adding `class="myclass"` is ignored by the controller. I've also tried with `@attributes` without success.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `validation-message` class inside the css file `app.css` inside the wwwroot. Or `site.css` in in earlier previews.

```css
.validation-message {
    color: red;
}
```

The class is set in `ValidationMessage.cs`

```cs
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
    foreach (var message in CurrentEditContext.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier))
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", "validation-message");
        builder.AddContent(3, message);
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs

Comment: I guess that is the way to go for the current version. Not what I wanted but not too bad.

Answer (score 4):

With .NET5 they added functionality to customize the validation classes on the actual **input-fields** (which [issue 8695](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8695) was about) by way of setting a `FieldCssClassProvider` to the edit context. But there still seems to be no way of customizing the classes of the `ValidationSummary` or `ValidationMessage` components

Snipped directly from the [.NET 5 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-validation-class-attributes)

```csharp
var editContext = new EditContext(model);
editContext.SetFieldCssClassProvider(new MyFieldClassProvider());

...

private class MyFieldClassProvider : FieldCssClassProvider
{
    public override string GetFieldCssClass(EditContext editContext, 
        in FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
    {
        var isValid = !editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();

        return isValid ? "good field" : "bad field";
    }
}
```

Using this will yield the below html for an invalid input. At least with this we can style the actual input elements. Just not the messages...

```html
<input class="bad field" aria-invalid="">
<div class="validation-message">Identifier too long (16 character limit).</div>
```

Comment: I completely missed that this was added to .NET 5!  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just copy the code for `ValidationMessage.cs` and write in your own property?  There is nothing special about this class except for capturing a Cascading Parameter.  Just take this file and make your own with a slightly different name then add:

```
[Parameter] public string AdditionalClassNames {get;set;}

protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
    foreach (var message in CurrentEditContext.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier))
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", string.IsNullOrEmpty(AdditionalClassNames) ? "validation-message" : $"validation-message {AdditionalClassNames}");
        builder.AddContent(3, message);
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs

#### EDIT

Even better, it's not sealed!  Just use it as a base class for a new version and add what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in ASP.NET Core 3.1. Hopefully, it will be included in next major version, see this feature request:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8695

Comment: You have this tagged for Blazor, if so can you use ```@attributes``` like the documentation outlines at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters?

Comment: No, I’ve tried @attributes too but that didn’t work either ☹

Comment: huh, I was able to get the attributes version going using the dictionary method they outline. Oddly though it would always add my class first, and then leave the original class in place.

Comment: @NikProtsman, I’ve just double checked and for me I can’t use `@attributes` to generate class on the `ValidationMessage`, but it works for other attributes.

Comment: You could just go in the source code, copy the `ValidationMessage` component and change the name of the class or create a parameter for the class name.