# Conditional classes with Blazor form validation

Tags: c#, blazor, tailwind-css

I'm trying out Blazor right now, with my choice of CSS framework being Tailwind.
Now, getting Tailwind built and integrated is easy enough, but I am struggling to find a resource on how to conditionally apply classes depending on an input validation state. Blazor itself adds an `invalid` class, but that obviously does not work with the styling approach Tailwind uses.
Basically I have this code:

```
<div class="mt-1">
    <InputText @bind-Value="LoginRequest.UserName" id="userName" type="text" required
                class="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"/>
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => LoginRequest.UserName)"/>
</div>
```

... and want to conditionally change, for example `border-gray-300` to `border-red-300` if the field validation failed.

Is this possible? If yes, I would love some pointers.

Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add to or change the default CSS class when using ValidationMessage in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367805/can-i-add-to-or-change-the-default-css-class-when-using-validationmessage-in-asp)

Comment: what have you done to achieve it so far add your code.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be possible with the new .NET 5 release:

```
<EditForm EditContext="@_loginContext">
 ... body ...
</EditForm>

@code{
    static UserLoginRequest LoginRequest { get; set; } = new();
    readonly EditContext _loginContext = new(LoginRequest);
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        _loginContext.SetFieldCssClassProvider(new TailwindClassProvider());
    }

    private class TailwindClassProvider : FieldCssClassProvider
    {
        public override string GetFieldCssClass(EditContext editContext, in FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
        {
            var isValid = !editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();

            return isValid ? "border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-400 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500" : "border-red-300 text-red-900 placeholder-red-300 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500";
        }
    }
}
```