# How to shrink the ValidationMessage string in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

I am new to blazor and currently working on a small project where I have a lot of text input fields on a page, which would be validated on submit. The page is responsive and would shrink into a column format when reducing device screen size. The message for a couple of validations is too long, and the string overflows out of its parent div element. What is a good way to fix that, and make the string break into multi-line?
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOUlk.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cvNL.png)

Comment: Add the code portion of adding the validation message in your question.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Hey. I added the code above.

Comment: You should add as textual code, rather than image files as per SO guidelines. The `ValidationMessage` will create its own `div` and render the error message. You can pass HTML attributes as additional attributes to that internally created div.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I'll keep that in mind, a little new to SO. So should I be able to use Style within ValidationMessage? If not, how do I access those properties?

Comment: the css class name is hard coded[to validation-message] in the ValidationMessage code, so you need to create custom ValidationMessage if you want to give it different css class name, see [this](https://chrissainty.com/creating-a-custom-validation-message-component-for-blazor-forms/)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Thanks a lot. I'll give that a read!

Comment: as a quick fix, you can add `word-wrap : break-word`  to class name `validation-message` inside the css file `app.css` inside the wwwroot folder, or in site.css

Comment: Take advantage of bootstrap's responsiveness. Use a container/row/column/form-group concept. Then you could wrap you validation message in a div that resizes automatically including wrapping by default.

Answer (score 0):

The default `ValidationMessage` component generates a `div` and assigns the css class 'validation-message' at rendering time. If you want to change the look and feel, you can do one of these :

- create a custom `ValidationMessage` c# class, and use your own css class (refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367805/can-i-add-to-or-change-the-default-css-class-when-using-validationmessage-in-asp) SO answer) or use bootstrap css etc
- quick and not so elegant fix, you can modify the `validation-message` class in your `app.css` or site.css file(s), so that it word wraps the lengthy error messages
- create a custom validator `blazor` component (as in [this](https://chrissainty.com/creating-a-custom-validation-message-component-for-blazor-forms/))